# set data structure in C++ that contains only one appearance of each class

Tags: c++, data-structures

I need to have a set (or any other data structure) that can contain only one instance of each class.
For example:
I have an interface A, and I have A1 that implement it.

I have the code:

```
std::set<A> myset;
A1 a1;
A1 a11;
myset.insert(a1); // should insert
myset.insert(a11);// should not insert
```

I want that `a11` will not be in the set.
I thought to do it with custom comparator, but I don't know how to  implement this comparator.

Any ideas?

Comment: `std::set<int>`? `A`? `A1`? Can you please clarify your problem. It isn't at all clear.

Comment: I think this kind of thing will be difficult until C++ gets reflection support.

Comment: You must decide what makes A1 different from A11 and write your compare object based on this. Class name, if I correctly understood your problem. For compare object there are plenty of examples on Internet.

Comment: Your comparison operator could use [`std::type_index()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index) which provides an order for `std::type_info` objects.

Comment: Your requirement sounds for me as if you want to make something similar like a [Factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Comment: Since you need a type that can hold references to all things you want to insert, you need a father class anyway, right? And if you have a father class, you can make it having a virtual method that returns what class each child is, maybe as a string. Is that together not enough to solve your problem? Or do you really need it to be able to actually take every class there is? That would be problematic because of the type the container is to be defined over.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to think `std::set` is a heterogenous container like `tuple` or `pair`.  But, like most C++ standard containers, it is a homogenous typed container, so you can only store a single type.

What you might consider is storing smart pointers, if all the classes you want to store are derived from a common base.  For example:

```
struct Base { virtual ~Base() {} };
struct A1 : Base {};
struct A2 : Base {};

struct myless {
    bool operator()(const std::unique_ptr<Base>& lhs, const std::unique_ptr<Base>& rhs) const
    {
        return typeid(*lhs).before(typeid(*rhs));
    }
};

std::set<std::unique_ptr<Base>, myless> myset;
myset.emplace(new A1()); // will insert
myset.emplace(new A1()); // will not insert
myset.emplace(new A2()); // will insert
myset.emplace(new A2()); // will not insert
```

Next, since `std::set` enforces that each value is unique according to a comparator which you can define, you'll need to define it in a way that it compares the type of each instance, rather than the value.  That's what `myless` does.

Comment: Hm, is it guaranteed that a `unique_ptr` is created even if not inserted?

Comment: @Aconcagua: It has to be, because otherwise how would `myless` be invoked in order to discover where or whether to insert it?

Comment: @John The `struct myless` could boil down to a `std::function<bool, const Base*,const Base*>` variable initialized with a lambda expression? Brilliant answer otherwise.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that has extra type erasure over a struct

Comment: WD, you got straight to the heart of it there.